# UpDown control works inversely than expected

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I have written a small program that creates an UpDown control associated to an Edit box.

I have tested with a resource script, and the problem is the same: the Up arrow decreases the number, and the Down arrow increases the number. I don't know where my error is.

I wrote the program on a Windows 11 machine with Visual Studio 2022.

Here is my code:

```c
#include <Windows.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>
#include "resource.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "comctl32.lib")

static HWND et1, ud1;
static HINSTANCE hinstancia;

LRESULT OnDestroy(HWND hwnd, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    return 0;
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
LRESULT OnCreate(HWND hwnd, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    et1 = CreateWindowEx(0, L"edit", L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 10, 10, 40, 16, hwnd, NULL, hinstancia, NULL);
    if (!et1)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"I was unable to create the input control", L"Error", MB_OK);
        exit(0);
    }
    ud1 = CreateWindowEx(0, L"MSCTLS_UPDOWN32", L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | UDS_ALIGNRIGHT | UDS_ARROWKEYS | UDS_AUTOBUDDY | UDS_SETBUDDYINT, 50, 10, 12, 16, hwnd, NULL, hinstancia, NULL);
    if (!ud1)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"I was unable to create the up down control", L"Error", MB_OK);
        exit(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
LRESULT CALLBACK wndproc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY: return OnDestroy(hwnd, wp, lp);
    case WM_CREATE: return OnCreate(hwnd, wp, lp);
    default: return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wp, lp);
    }
    
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX ice;
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;
    hinstancia = hInstance;
    ice.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
    ice.dwICC = ICC_UPDOWN_CLASS;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&ice);
    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"Test1";
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject(GRAY_BRUSH);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.lpfnWndProc = wndproc;
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window class was not registered", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW, L"Test1", L"Sample", WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_VISIBLE,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 400, 300, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    if (!hwnd)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window was not createed", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }
    ShowWindow(hwnd, nShowCmd);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);  
    }
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

I expected to increment the number with the Up arrow and decrement it with the Down arrow.

Comment: Please edit your question and add a tag for the programming language this is written in.

Comment: You need to set a range on the control.  That's Windows way of telling you it isn't configured properly.

Comment: Per MSDN [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/up-down-controls): "*You can change the minimum and maximum positions of an up-down control by using the UDM_SETRANGE message. The maximum position may be less than the minimum, and **in that case clicking the up arrow button decreases the current position**. To put it another way, up means moving toward the maximum position. To retrieve the minimum and maximum positions for an up-down control, use the UDM_GETRANGE message.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Remy Lebeau,

According to the Doc:[Step 7: Create the Up-Down Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/create-an-up-down-control#step-7-create-the-up-down-control)

> To get the control to count upward when the user clicks the control's
> up arrow, you must set the up-down control's range and direction. You
> do this by sending the control a `UDM_SETRANGE` message that contains
> values for upper and lower bounds.

Here is the code:

```
SendMessage(ud1, UDM_SETRANGE, 0, UDM_GETRANGE);
```

And you could refer to the sample:[Up-Down Control Sample Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/create-an-up-down-control#up-down-control-sample-code)

You could also set the range of values for the Up-Down control as you like:

```
const UINT valMin=0;          // The range of values for the Up-Down control.
const UINT valMax=100;

SendMessage(hControl, UDM_SETRANGE, 0, MAKELPARAM(valMax, valMin));    // Sets the controls direction 
                                                                       // and range.
```

Comment: That would set the upper bound of the range to 1126 (the value of `UDM_GETRANGE`) which is probably not what is desired.

Comment: UDM_SETRANGE solved the problem. I added SendMessage(ud1, UDM_SETRANGE, 0, MAKELPARAM(100, 0)); and it works perfect. Thanks to all of you for your attention.

Comment: @JoséAntonioLópezCano We are appreciate that you are satisfied with the help we provide. If your case has been solved, please help to mark answer and this will be beneficial to other community.